# Finding circle with maximum diameter

Tags: geometry

Given a circle $C$ defined by Set $S$ of $3$ points $S = ${$a$,$b$,$c$}, I wish to find $w ∈ C, w ∉ S$, Such that The circle $C'$ Defined by {$w$, $a'$,$b'$} And $a',b' ∈ S$, Will have the maximum diameter.

Is this even possible?

Does there even exist such circle with Max diameter? Is it bounded?

I thought that since the diameter is continuous, A circle with maximum diameter doesn't even exist, Because we could always find a "better" $w ∈ C$ Which will produce a circle with larger diameter.

Any assistance will be appericiated.

Comment: Imagine the three points _almost_ sitting on one line. The circle will be large as life, only larger, and could easily be made larger yet.

Comment: Since $w, a^\prime, b^\prime \in C$ I would expect $C^\prime$ be the same as $C$ -- or am I missing something here? Is your "circle" a curve or the whole area inside the curve?